# How can I correctly check if a value is a number using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

into a JQuery sccript I do something like this to check if the value inserted into an input field having **id="variazioneAnticipo** is a number:

```
var variazioneAnticipo = $("#variazioneAnticipo").val();

if($.isNumeric(variazioneAnticipo)) {
    alert("NUMBER");
}
else {
     alert("NOT A NUMBER");
}
```

This works fine but the only problem is that the **isNumeric()** JQuery function considers numbers also the **exponential notation** and other notation that I don't want to be considered number.

How can see here: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isNumeric/ these notations are considered number:

```
$.isNumeric( 0xFF );      // true
$.isNumeric( "0xFF" );    // true
$.isNumeric( "8e5" );     // true (exponential notation string)
```

How can I prevent that these notations are considered number? Can I specify in some way what for me is a number and what not using the **isNumeric()** function?

Or what can I do to say if a value is a number without taking into account the previous cases?

Comment: Use regex `/^[0-9]+$/.test(value)`

Comment: @Tushar Needs to handle float numbers too, i guess

Comment: If you want to consider float numbers, then use `/^[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?$/`

Comment: @Tushar ok...if you add a response and show me how to use in my code the regex that check also float number I will accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Use `pattern` attribute on `input`
2. Bind keyup event on the input
3. When value entered, check if the value satisfies the float regex

```js
$('#num').on('keyup', function() {
  var value = $(this).val();

  if (/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?$/.test(value)) {
    $('#message').text('Valid');
  } else {
    $('#message').text('Invalid');
  }
});
```

```css
#num:invalid {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" pattern="[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?" id="num" />
<div id="message"></div>
```

[**Regex Explanation:**](https://regex101.com/r/iU6lI5/1)

```
/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?$/
```

1. `^`: Start of line
2. `[0-9]+`: Matches one or more occurrences of number from 0 to 9
3. `(\.[0-9]+)?`: Matches one or more occurrences of number followed by a decimal point. The whole group can occur zero or once.
4. `$`: End of line

**Same code with just HTML and CSS**

```css
#valid,
#invalid {
  display: none;
}
#num:invalid,
#invalid {
  color: red;
}
#num:valid,
#valid {
  color: green;
}
#num:invalid ~ #invalid {
  display: block;
}
#num:valid + #valid {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" pattern="[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?" id="num" />
<div id="valid">Valid</div>
<div id="invalid">Invalid</div>
```

Comment: Works now, LoL. Can you remove the invalid when nothing is there? Simple fix! `:P`

Comment: @tushar why are you using scripts,  if it works fine with input field & css that you have posted..?

Comment: @DiveshOswal Not all browsers support HTML5's `pattern` attribute.

Comment: @DiveshOswal Added code without jQuery too, at the bottom of answer

Answer (score 2):

Extending [Tushar's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2025923/tushar) [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34333009/how-can-i-correctly-check-if-a-value-is-a-number-using-jquery#comment56407408_34333009), putting it an answer with a fiddle that checks:

```js
$(function () {
  $("#out").click(function () {
    alert(/^[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?$/.test($("#in").val()) ? "Yes" : "No");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="in" />
<input type="submit" value="Check" id="out" />
```

Works perfectly for numbers, float values, and not Hex or Exponential.

Comment: Thanks for the attribution

Comment: @Tushar That's what is called as decency. Decently nicking code! `:P`